# Mipmapping with generating textures in xna

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, mipmaps, dynamic-content

I'm generating some textures in my game, but I need mipmaps for them. Why are there no mipmaps generating even when I'm setting mipMap to true in the constructor and how can I generate the mipmaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to perform the downscaling yourself, and then fill each mipmap level yourself.

You can use [this version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434430) of `SetData` to specify which mipmap level you are setting.

Use the `LevelCount` property to determine how many mipmap levels were created by the constructor.